# Why does a public variable define a private one?

Tags: unity, c#

What is the point of such work with variables?

```
public GameObject Obj => _obj;
[SerializeField] private GameObject _obj;
```

A private variable loses its privacy when we create a public variable that defines a private one.
For me it looks meaningless and only confuses.

Comment: This practice of creating a private "backing field" to support a public property is not unique to game development, so this is the kind of general programming practice question that you can find answered on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't create a public *variable* that defines a private one, it creates a public [**property**](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties). Using a property allows you to later add code you always want to get executed when that variable is getting set and/or read. This is not happening in this example (yet), but when you create properties like this preemptively, then it gets a lot easier to add this functionality later.

Further, this particular syntax creates a property which can only be read but not written. That means that other scripts can find out what `_obj` this component references, but they can not change it. There are often situations where changing a variable like that at runtime can lead to unexpected behavior. For example, when you do some stuff with that gameObject in `Start()`. So when you write a MonoBehavior which does not support changing a variable at runtime, then it's a good idea to follow this pattern so that nobody later thinks they can do that without causing any weird bugs.